# How long is an arrow in the air?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

The height $h$ of an arrow in feet is modeled by $h(t) = -16t^2 + 63t + 4$, where $t$ is the time in seconds since the arrow was shot. How long is the arrow in the air?

Could someone explain where to start? I am stumped on this question.

Answer (score 3):

HINT: Solve to find the time $t$ at which $h(t)$, the height of the arrow above the ground, is $0$. This is just a matter of solving a quadratic equation.

Comment: @FlybyNight: I was leaving that point for Daniel to realize.